# How to convert this JSP to an MVC approach?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp

I've written the below JSP. Now I want to make it into a MVC pattern, could you please help me how to do it?

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>  
<%@include file="DBCon.jsp" %>  
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
<title>Insert title here</title>  
<script language="javascript">  
    function UnBloc1(test){  
        var temp3id= 'temp3' + test;  
        var temp4id= 'temp4' + test;  
      //alert(temp3id);  

      document.getElementById(temp3id).style.display='block';  
      document.getElementById(temp4id).style.display='block';  
    }  

    function invoke(but1)  
    {  
        //var x=document.getElementById("temp3"+but).value;  
        //alert(x);  
         document.abc.action="Up_Query_DB.jsp?val1="+but1;  
         document.abc.submit();  
    }  
    function invoke1(but)  
            {      
         document.abc.action="Users_2.jsp?val="+but;  
         document.abc.submit();  

         //var t=document.getElementById("ab")+z;  
         //alert(t);  
            }  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form name="abc" method="post" action=""><table>  
<%  
try  
               {  
    String s=(String)session.getAttribute("muusername");  
    int i=0;  
    int temp=0, temp1=0,temp2=0, temp3=0, temp4=0;  
    ps=con.prepareStatement("Select DBID,Query_Raised,TR from Scope2 where TR!='null' AND (Query_Answered is null OR Count1 is null) And Specialist='"+s+"'");  
    rs=ps.executeQuery();  
    out.println("<b>QueryRaised</b>");  
       while(rs.next())  

        {  

           i++;  
           %>  

                      <tr>  
                      <td><input type="text" value="<%=i%>" name="id1" id="id1"></td>  
                      <td><center><input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("DBID")%>" readonly id="abc<%=i%>" name="abc<%=i%>" size="100"></center></td>  
                      <td><input type="Submit" value="Resume" name="temp1<%=i%>" id="temp1<%=i%>" onclick="invoke1(<%=i%>)"></td>  
                      <td><input type="button" value="Update Answer"  name="temp2<%=i%>" id="temp2<%=i%>" onClick="UnBloc1(<%=i%>)"></td>  
                      <td><input type="text" name="temp3<%=i%>" id="temp3<%=i%>" style="display: none"/></td>   
                      <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" name="temp4<%=i%>" id="temp4<%=i%>" style="display: none" onClick="invoke(<%=i%>)"/>                      </td>  
                      </tr>  



    <% }  

}  
catch(Exception e)  
           {  

out.println(e);  

}  
%>    
  </table>    
 </form>   


</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: An excellent [tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) for data layer from BalusC

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you go to the database and get a list of objects that contain few attributes (with setter and getter methods), among them, the `dbid` attribute. The object would be your model. Let's call it `myBean`.

The Java class from you will do the query will be the Controller class. Let's call it `myController`. So, the controller should: 1. Get the list of objects you need. 2. Do anything that should be done before representing the information (in your case, I would say nothing) and 3. pass the information to the JSP through the list of your beans setting the information in the request so the information can be displayed.

Your JSP, now, should look like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
    <title>Insert title here</title>

    <script language="javascript">

       ...

    </script>  
</head>  

<body>

<form name="abc" method="post" action="">

    <table>

        <c:forEach var="myItem" items="${listDbid}" varStatus="i">

            <tr>  
                <td><input type="text" value="${i.count}" name="id1" id="id1"></td>  
                <td><center><input type="text" value="${myItem.getDbid}" readonly id="abc${i.count}" name="abc${i.count}" size="100"></center></td>  
                <td><input type="Submit" value="Resume" name="temp1${i.count}" id="temp1${i.count}" onclick="invoke1(${i.count})"></td>  
                <td><input type="button" value="Update Answer"  name="temp2${i.count}" id="temp2${i.count}" onClick="UnBloc1(${i.count})"></td>  
                <td><input type="text" name="temp3${i.count}" id="temp3${i.count}" style="display: none"/></td>   
                <td><input type="Submit" value="Submit Answer" name="temp4${i.count}" id="temp4${i.count}" style="display: none" onClick="invoke(${i.count})"/>                      </td>  
            </tr>    

        </c:forEach>        

  </table>    
 </form>      

</body>  
</html>
```

So, basically, you need to remove from your JSP all the code that is not "view", take it to a "controller" and use a "model" for sending the information from the "controller" to the "view".

Also

- You should avoid scriptles (<% %>) in your JSP, better to use JSTL and others similar tools. If you do it, probably your JSP will not have "controller" code.
- I recommend you to use a MVC framework, like Spring MVC or Struts, among others.
- It is also nice if you create another layer in your code just for database access. This database layer will be used by the controllers so the controllers. You can reuse code, make controllers independent of database and keep them clearer.

Comment: Neat, +1. Rakesh, when he's saying Spring MVC or Struts, he is saying Spring MVC or Struts2.

Answer (score 1):

I am new too MVC as well, but I can suggest you some tips. Make a bean. Beans are Java class with getter and setter. In your case the bean would be

```
 public class Scope2
 {
   String dbID;
  //all other attributes of the table.Beans should be reusable so usually there is only one bean for one corresponding table

   public String getDBID()
  {
    return dbID;
   }
   public void setDBID(String dbId)
   {
     this.dbId=dbId;
   }

  //Other getters and setters for all other attributes
}
```

Now make a class that would perform database query. And return bean Scope2 from that class to jsp. And in your jsp you will simply print the values as out.println(bean.getDBID());